# antlr4 grammar - how to match EOF/NL

Tags: antlr4

How would I match a file where the last line has no newline at the
end. When I use the commented line (w/EOF) the parser goes into what
looks like an infinite loop (i.e it hangs).

Here is a grammar - mostly borrowed from tparr's work

```
grammar csv;

prog : row+ ;
row :  field (',' field)* NL;
// row :  field (',' field)* (NL|EOF); // doesn't work

field : STR | QSTR | ; // field can be empty

STR : ~[\n,"]+ ;
QSTR : Q (QQ|~'"')* Q ;
NL : '\n';

fragment QQ : '""' ;
fragment Q : '"' ;
```

And here is the corresponding data file.

```
Details,Month,Amount
Mid Bonus,June,"$2,000"
,January,"""zippo"""
Total Bonuses,"","$5,000"<EOF is on the same line>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parser goes to an infinite loop because your `rule` row (the variant which includes `EOF`) can match an empty input string at the end:

- `field` can match the empty string
- `(',' field)*` can obviously match the empty string because of the `*` quantifier
- the `EOF` token *cannot* be consumed (ie it occurs an infinite amount of times), so it can be matched multiple times.

Instead of thinking about a row as ending with a newline, why don't you think of the newline as a row separator instead:

```
prog : row (NL row)* EOF;
row  : field (',' field)*;
```

That's untested but should work fine.

Comment: Excellent - that works.. thanks for helping me understand EOF handling as well.